# Best approach to render MediaWiki in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, parsing, .net-core, mediawiki

Question:

I want to render MediaWiki syntax (and I mean MediaWiki syntax as used by WikiPedia, not some other wiki format from some other engine such as WikiPlex), and that in C#.

Input: MediaWiki Markup string
Output: HTML string

There are some alternative mediawiki parsers, but nothing in C#, and additionally pinvoking C/C++ looks bleak, because of the structure of those libaries.

As syntax guidance, I  use
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Cheatsheet

My first goal is to render that page's markup correctly.

Markup can be seen here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Wikipedia:Cheatsheet&action=edit

Now, if I use Regex, it's not of much use, because one can't exactly say which tag ends which starting ones, especially when some elements, such as italic, become an attribute of the parent element.

On the other hand, parsing character by character is not a good approach either, because 
for example ''' means bold, '' means italic, and ''''' means bold and italic...

I looked into porting some of the other parsers' code, but the java implementations are obscure, and the Python implementations have have a very different regex syntax.

The best approach I see so far would be to port mwlib to IronPython
http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Alternative_parsers

But frankly, I'm not looking forward to having the IronPython runtime added as a dependency to my application, and even if I would want to, the documentation is bad at best.

Comment: Take a look at how WikiPlex does it.  All you have to do at that point is modify it.

Comment: @Ramhound: Good idea. I think they use regex, AFAIK. Not sure if that works for MediaWiki though, as it's a bit more complex. Plus they render everything to HTML tags, so no css, and no attributes, but lots of deprecated tags, such as <b> or <i>.

Comment: What about "Kiwi"? (https://github.com/aboutus/kiwi, mentioned on http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Alternative_parsers). Since it is C based, and I/O is simply done by stdin/stdout, it should not be too hard to create a "PInvoke"-able DLL from it.

Comment: @Doc Brown: On trying to compile it, I get: leg -o src/syntax.leg "make: leg: command not found"

Comment: Ah, now it compiles, needed to fix the makefile, compiler not defined,... a very bad sign IMHO...

Comment: @Quandary: leg is a parser generator (http://piumarta.com/software/peg/), dunno how portable this thing is. Perhaps you should contact the authors of kiwi to ask them if the thing can be compiled with MSVC. I did not post my comment as an answer because I did not try this on my own, and don't know if this approach is worth the effort.

Comment: @Doc Brown: I found that out in the meantime, too. However, it compiles with MinGW, so I don't even need msvc. I just need to create the C file from the leg file, which I can do on my Linux system. After that I simply take the C file, and compile it on Windows with MinGW + msys.

Comment: @Quandary: interesting, I have never tried to PInvoke functions from a DLL build with GCC - does that work painless?

Comment: @Doc Brown: MinGW gcc, unlike cygwin, creates native windows binaries (no Unix emulation). Created dll's work just fine with LoadLibrary, and since DllImport is nothing more than a wrapper around LoadLibrary, pinvoking works fine. PS: leg also works fine on windows, when compiled with gcc (same adjustment to the makefile).

Comment: @Doc Brown: Splendid, I have it working (except Unicode) !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update per 2017:**
You can use [ParseoidSharp](https://github.com/ststeiger/ParseoidSharp) to get a fully compatible MediaWiki-renderer.
It uses the official Wikipedia [Parsoid](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Alternative_parsers) library via NodeServices.
(NetStandard 2.0)
Since Parsoid is GPL 2.0, and and the GPL-code is invoked in nodejs in a separate process via network, you can even use any license you like ;)

---

**Pre-2017**

Problem solved. 
As originally assumed, the solution lies in using one of the existing alternative parsers in C#.
 
WikiModel (Java) works well for that purpose.

First attempt was pinvoke kiwi. 
It worked, but but failed because:

- kiwi uses char* (fails on anything non-English/ASCII)
- not thread safe.
- bad because of the need have a native dll in the code for every architecture 
  (did add x86 and amd64, then it went kaboom on my ARM processor)

Second attempt was mwlib. 
That failed because somehow IronPython doesn't work as it should.

Third attempt was Swebele, which essentially turned out to be academic vapoware.

The fourth attempt was using the original mediawiki renderer, using Phalanger. That failed because the MediaWiki renderer is not really modular.

The fifth attempt was using Wiky.php via Phalanger, which worked, but was slow and Wiky.php doesn't very completely implement MediaWiki.

The sixth attempt was using bliki via ikvmc, which failed because of the excessive use of 3rd party libraries ==> it compiles, but yields null-reference exceptions only

The seventh attempt was using JavaScript in C#, which worked but was very slow, plus the MediaWiki functionality implemented was very incomplete.

The 8th attempt was writing an own "parser" via Regex. 
But the time required to make it work is just excessive, so I stopped.

The 9th attempt was successful. 
Using ikvmc on WikiModel yields a useful dll. 
The problem there was the example-code was hoplessly out of date. 
But using google and the WikiModel sourcecode, I was able to piece it together.

The end-result can be found here:
https://github.com/ststeiger/MultiWikiParser

Answer (score 2):

Why shouldn't this be possible with regular expressions?

```
inputString = Regex.Replace(inputString, @"(?:'''''')(.*?)(?:'''''')", @"<strong><em>$1</em></strong>");
inputString = Regex.Replace(inputString, @"(?:''')(.*?)(?:''')", @"<strong>$1</strong>");
inputString = Regex.Replace(inputString, @"(?:'')(.*?)(?:'')", @"<em>$1</em>");
```

This will, as far as I can see, render all 'Bold and italic', 'Bold' and 'Italic' text.

Comment: Because there are such things as nested lists (with enumeration) and tables.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I once implemented a solution:

- define your regular expressions for Markup->HTML conversion
- regular expressions must be non greedy
- collect the regular expressions in a `Dictionary<char, List<RegEx>>`

The char is the first (Markup) character in each RegEx, and RegEx's must be sorted by Markup keyword length desc, e.g. `===` before `==`.

Iterate through the characters of the input string, and check if Dictionary.ContainsKey(char). If it does, search the List for matching RegEx. First matching RegEx wins.

As MediaWiki allows recursive markup (except for <pre> and others), the string inside the markup must also be processed in this fashion recursively.

If there is a match, skip ahead the number of characters matching the RegEx in input string. Otherwise proceed to next character.

Answer (score 0):

Kiwi (https://github.com/aboutus/kiwi, mentioned on http://mediawiki.org/wiki/Alternative_parsers) may be a solution. Since it is C based, and I/O is simply done by stdin/stdout, it should not be too hard to create a "PInvoke"-able DLL from it.

Answer (score 0):

As with the accepted solution I found parsoid is the best way forward as it's the official library - and has the greatest support for the wikimedia markup; that said I found ParseoidSharp to be using obsolete methods such as Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices and really it's just a wrapper for a fairly old version of pasoid's npm package.

Since there is a fairly current version of parsoid in node.js you can use Jering.Javascript.NodeJS to do the same thing as ParseoidSharp, the steps are fairly similar also.

1. Install nodeJS (
2. download parsoid https://www.npmjs.com/package/parsoid place the required files in your  project.
3. in powershell cd to your project
4. npm install

Then it's as simple as

```
output = StaticNodeJSService.InvokeFromFileAsync(Of String)(HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath & "./NodeScripts/parsee.js", args:=New Object() {Markup})
```

Bonus it's now much easier than ParseoidSharp's method to add the options required, e.g. you'll probably want to set the domain to your own domain.